# Flutter Firestore queries. I need to start from a specific index to show a order list

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called Categories in Firestore. Each category has an index manually added. When I loop through the categories to display them on the UI by using GridView, the order of the categories is chosen by the way they've been created originally in Firestore.

Here my code at the moment:
**database.dart**

```
Future<List<CategoriesModel>> getCategoriesList({String partnerStoreId}) async {
    List<CategoriesModel> categories = List();
    List<ProductsModel> products = List();

    QuerySnapshot snapshot;
    // Products
    snapshot = await productsCollection
        .where('partnerInfo.storeId', isEqualTo: '$partnerStoreId')
        .getDocuments();

    products = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => ProductsModel.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
    
    // Categories
    snapshot = await categoriesCollection.getDocuments();
    categories =
        snapshot.documents.map((doc) => CategoriesModel.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();


    int ind = 0;
    categories.forEach((category) {
      products.forEach((product) {
        if(product.category == category.enId) {
          category.productCount = category.productCount + 1;
        }
      });
      categories[ind] = category;

      ind++;
    });

    return categories;
  }
```

In Firestore, each category has a key called `ux` and inside a sub key called `index` where a number has been manually added.

Problem: When I display the categories in the UI, I need to display first `ux.index = 11`, followed by `ux.index = 3` and then everything else.

I'm trying to change this line:

```
snapshot = await categoriesCollection.getDocuments();
```

and I'm trying to use .where, startAt, orderBy etc.... which will query Firestore.
Here some of the examples I've tried:

```
// Here only number 11 is displayed
snapshot = await categoriesCollection.where('ux.index', isEqualTo: 11).getDocuments(); 

// Here nothing is displayed
snapshot = await categoriesCollection.where('ux.index', isEqualTo: 11).where('ux.index', isEqualTo: 3).getDocuments(); 

// Nothing is displayed, and even if I use only isLessThanOrEqualTo, the number 11 item is still NOT the first
snapshot = await categoriesCollection.where('ux.index', isLessThanOrEqualTo: 11).where('ux.index', isGreaterThan: 11).getDocuments();
```

Can someone help please? It's driving me nuts at the moment.
Thanks in advance
Joe

Comment: can you please post what your firestore data tree structure looks like? including categoriesCollection, and the way you stored ux.subkeys

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain why your last two queries return nothing.

using multiple `where` means `and` which allows you to pass multiple queries at once. Literally it is like `query1 and query2 and ...`

See explanation below.

```
// Here nothing is displayed
snapshot = await categoriesCollection.where('ux.index', isEqualTo: 11).where('ux.index', isEqualTo: 3).getDocuments();
```

because, you are asking for `ux.index == 11` **and** `ux.index == 3`
which naturally returns nothing.

and here

```
snapshot = await categoriesCollection.where('ux.index', isLessThanOrEqualTo: 11).where('ux.index', isGreaterThan: 11).getDocuments();
```

because, you are asking for `ux.index <= 11` **and** `ux.index >= 11`
which naturally returns nothing, because condition is not applicable.

**A potential solution** for your need:
First, please replace
`snapshot = await categoriesCollection.getDocuments();`
with
`snapshot = await categoriesCollection.where('ux.index', descending: false).getDocuments();`

Assuming that `ux.index` begins with 0 and increments till more than 11.

Thereafter, please replace
`return categories;`
with the code-snippet below.

```
List orderedCategories = List();  
// cherry-pick 11 and 3  
orderedCategories.add(categories[11]);  
categories.removeAt(11); 
orderedCategories.add(categories[3]);  
categories.removeAt(3);
// add all the rest
orderedCategories.addAll(categories);  

return orderedCategories;
```

nb! that's a quick solution which can be optimized.